# VSCode extension. Inject types into untitled file

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing an extension that uses some library and want to inject typings for the library into a `.js` file that opens when I call a command from my extension. How to make autocompletion work for a specific file not altering user's workspace? May be inject types at the top of the file and collapse block (I'm pretty new to extension development and don't know is it possible at all)?

Comment: Do you want to automatically generate a file and fill it with some imports?

Comment: @heatherp I want to turn on autocomplete with specific library typings (implicit import)